# Drawing lines on canvas with IE9 lags

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, canvas, jcanvas

I've recently tried to create a simple painter using canvas. I used mousedown to capture the starting point. On mousemove I drew a line from the starting point to the current point and replaced the starting point with the current point. Finally I removed the event handlers on mouseup. This solution worked perfectly on Chrome,Firefox and safari but when I tested it on IE9 I encountered an annoying bug. The lines that I draw only appear after the mouseup event. Any ideas as to why this is happening and how should I fix it?

I've added a simple test page to demonstrate the issue
http://kfirg.com/rage/main.htm
Try to draw a long line, or a circle or something like that. On chrome it will work perfectly but on IE9 it will lag like crazy.

Notes:
I've used jQuery and jCanvas for this simple painter. I also tried implementing it myself using the canvas api directly and I encountered the same issue.

Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t5QpN/1/

Comment: I found this demo online
http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/CanvasPad/Default.html
Look at the mouse demo, and it works like a charm in IE there, but I can't seem to find the difference between that code and mine. If anyone could help me figure out the difference it would be great.

Comment: After some playing around I've found out that if I clear the canvas like so
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.05)";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
Than the performance on IE is much better, anyone can explain why?
Another method is doing 
canvas.width = canvas.width;
canvas.height = canvas.height;

Answer (score 1):

You actually have more bugs than that in IE. From my tests, the lines are sporadically drawn.

[I made a jsFiddle of this to test](http://jsfiddle.net/t5QpN/).

I don't have answers just ideas. I've never down a pencil drawing type canvas app like this, I've done it with polling when the mouse is down. It's obvious that your draw code IS running as you expected in IE if you look at the console.  Mouse move must IS firing as much as you want.

So what could the deal be.  I'm thinking one of two things

1. IE is too busy with something else in the thread to draw canvas until after the mouse is up
2. (Related to 1) Perhaps you are drawing too often and overloading it

If either of these two are correct, I think you need to switch to polling every X milliseconds for the position of the mouse.  It won't give you as smooth of a line, but you can adjust X until it's something that looks good.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That seems to have done the trick! one question though, which function did you use for the pooling? setTimeout,setInterval,requestAnimationFrame

Comment: I used setTimeout and then reset it if required.  I'm not sure if it matters either way.

Comment: Well sadly I checked with an older version of ie and was running on flashcanvas instead of the native ie one. It seems like on flashcanvas this works like it should but on the regular ie it doesn't :(

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is heavy for a mousemove event :

```
 var fncMouseMoveHandler = function (e) {
        console.log('Move!', 'e', { x: e.offsetX, y: e.offsetY }, 'prev', prev);
        $main_canvas.drawLine({
            strokeStyle: settings.color,
            strokeWidth: 2,
            strokeCap: "round",
            strokeJoin: "miter",
            x1: prev.x,
            y1: prev.y,
            x2: e.offsetX,
            y2: e.offsetY
        });
        prev = { x: e.offsetX, y: e.offsetY };
    }
```

You are using an API, applying style and calculating not needed things. The code for drawing should be that simple : 
You get the coordinates, and draw with :

```
context.lineTo(x, y);
context.stroke();
```

the styles of your stroke should not be defined in your mousemove event, the canvas will remember the settings.

A great tutorial is available at opera dev center : http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html5-canvas-painting/